# could not find implicit value for param in scala

Tags: scala, implicit

Stuck with a compilation error in my scala code
that reads implicit value could not be found . Could somebody point out what I am doing wrong?

Error :

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type scopt.Read[Array[String]]
      opt[Array[String]](
                        ^
one error found
```

My code

```
case class Myclass ( 

listC: Array[String] = Array()

)

object Myclass { 

 def parseArgs(args: Seq[String]): Myclass = {
    val parser = new scopt.OptionParser[Myclass](
      "ValidateData") {

     
      opt[Array[String]](
        "disabled.implicit.assertions") optional () action { (x, c) =>
        c.copy(disabledImplicitAssertions = x)
      }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I don't think scopt has an instance of `Read` for `Array`, use `Seq` instead. If you want to use `Array` you probably need to define your own reader, or have an implicit conversion from `Seq`. Or to be honest I would recommend using `decline` over `scopt` all together.

Comment: @sinanspd : Sorry, I am super new to scala.

How exactly do you propose the implicit conversion from `seq` ?

Comment: See if this helps: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-conversions.html